# Add a Scrap Mechanic tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-creation

Scrap Mechanic is a (semi) popular creative/survival sandbox game, and could much use a tag on Arqade.
The game on steam: [Scrap Mechanic](https://store.steampowered.com/app/387990/Scrap_Mechanic/).

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @CATboardBETA, welcome to Arqade! Tags can't exist without questions, so if you have a question about Scrap Mechanic - ask it and tag with something related, like the platform it's on. Be sure to state the game name clearly in either the title or question body - someone will edit to add the tag for you.

Comment: @Robotnik Understood, will do.